# Web-Pack 4.0 : Not able to copy files after build

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

This is my config file and it is bundling and generating the build files in the desired 'dist' directory. But I want to copy it to some other location. The problem is that the copyWebPackPlugin is running a bit earlier before the build is completed.

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const buildAssets= require('./frontEndBuildAssets');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')


var vendorJsFiles = buildAssets.buildConfig.vendorJs;
var frontEndStyles = buildAssets.buildConfig.frontEndStyles;
var customJsFiles = buildAssets.buildConfig.customJSFiles;


let pathsToClean = [
    'dist/assets'
]


const frontEndBuildConfig = {
    entry: {'vendorJs':vendorJsFiles,'customJs':customJsFiles,'frontEndStyles':frontEndStyles},
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/assets',
        filename: '[name]Bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap!', options: { minimize: true,sourceMap: true} }
                    ]
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: './fonts'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/indexTemplate.html',
            inject: true,
            filename: 'index.html'
         }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                exclude: /(costing)/,
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                    beautify: true
                },
                compress: {},
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('frontEndStylesBundle.css'),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: path.resolve(__dirname,'import/importFromExcel.html'),
                to:path.resolve(__dirname,'costing/assets/')}])
    ]
};


 module.exports = [frontEndBuildConfig];
```

After running webpack --mode development i am not getting any files at the desired location.

Answer (score 2):

It is the normal behaviour of `CopyWebpackPlugin`. It copies files earlier WebPack runs, not after, so you must search other way to achieve this.

**THEORY**

For solve your problem yo can do two things:

- Exports an array of configs:

  ```
  module.exports = [
  {
      name: "mobile",
      // mode: "development || "production",
      entry: "./example",
      output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
          filename: "mobile.js"
      },
      plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              ENV: JSON.stringify("mobile")
          })
      ]
  },

  {
      name: "desktop",
      // mode: "development || "production",
      entry: "./example",
      output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
          filename: "desktop.js"
      },
      plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              ENV: JSON.stringify("desktop")
          })
      ]
  }
  ];
  ```
- Or create a common config and create two separate configs too (one for each output) and then, exports them

  ```
  var config = {
      // TODO: Add common Configuration
      module: {},
  };

  var fooConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
      name: "a",
      entry: "./a/app",
      output: {
         path: "./a",
         filename: "bundle.js"
      },
  });
  var barConfig = Object.assign({}, config,{
      name: "b",
      entry: "./b/app",
      output: {
         path: "./b",
         filename: "bundle.js"
      },
  });

  // Return Array of Configurations
  module.exports = [
      fooConfig, barConfig,       
  ];
  ```

Both ways are equal.

---

**PRACTIQUE**

In your case, should be something like:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const buildAssets= require('./frontEndBuildAssets');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')


var vendorJsFiles = buildAssets.buildConfig.vendorJs;
var frontEndStyles = buildAssets.buildConfig.frontEndStyles;
var customJsFiles = buildAssets.buildConfig.customJSFiles;


let pathsToClean = [
    'dist/assets'
]


const frontEndBuildConfig = {
    entry:   {'vendorJs':vendorJsFiles,'customJs':customJsFiles,'frontEndStyles':frontEndStyles},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap!', options: { minimize: true,sourceMap: true} }
                    ]
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                   options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: './fonts'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/indexTemplate.html',
            inject: true,
            filename: 'index.html'
         }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                exclude: /(costing)/,
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                    beautify: true
                },
                compress: {},
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('frontEndStylesBundle.css'),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: path.resolve(__dirname,'import/importFromExcel.html'),
            to:path.resolve(__dirname,'costing/assets/')}])
    ]
};

const outputOne = Object.assign({}, frontEndBuildConfig, {
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/assets',
        filename: '[name]Bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
});

const outputTwo = Object.assign({}, frontEndBuildConfig, {
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/otherAssetsFromOutputTwo',
        filename: '[name]Bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
});

 module.exports = [outputOne, outputTwo];
```